# Two vastly different counts using queries found here... what's the difference?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, automationstudio, sql

As a SQL neophyte, I know enough to be dangerous.

I have two queries, both found here... the first is the one I'm directed to to answer "who hasn't opened an email in xx days".

```
SELECT 
   s.SubscriberKey,
   s.EventDate AS Sent_Date,
  'False' AS Not_Opened
FROM _Sent s  
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
   WHERE  o.SubscriberKey IS NULL AND
          CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(dd, -90, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) AND
          CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND
          s.SubscriberKey like 'value_%'
```

The second I also found here, and it appears to do the same thing.

```
SELECT  s.SubscriberKey
FROM    _Sent s 
WHERE 
s.EventDate > dateadd(day,-90,getdate())  AND 
s.SubscriberKey NOT IN 
       ( 
        SELECT o.SubscriberKey FROM _Open o
        WHERE  o.EventDate >  dateadd(day,-90,getdate())
        )
AND s.SubscriberKey like 'value_%
```

Except the first one pulls in 530K and the second is 665K.

This is really throwing me for a loop!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers might be different because you are not using same date filter conditions in your two queries and also you are not casting (s.eventdate) to date type.

Can you check again with this modified second query.

```
SELECT  s.SubscriberKey
FROM    _Sent s
WHERE
CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(dd, -90, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) AND
CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AND
s.SubscriberKey NOT IN
(
SELECT o.SubscriberKey FROM _Open o
WHERE  CAST(o.EventDate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(dd, -90,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
)
AND s.SubscriberKey like 'value_%'
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't really follow the concept of CASTing to date type, since the field is already Date/Time.

Comment: EventDate is date/time field so it contains the time parameter. Here we are removing the time parameter from the event date by casting to just date so we can accurately filter the subscribers just based on date.

Comment: OK, makes sense... is the suggestion then that inclusion of the time stamp would result in a 20% difference?  seems unlikely that 100K are excluded because of a time stamp.

Comment: I think the count difference is major because of the missing date filter (CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) in the second query.